# Multiple threads and a single main object variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a variable and I create few thread in loop like this

```
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
        int start = 0;  
        while(nThreads > 0) {
        nThreads--;
        service.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
      }
```

Now I want every thread to use value start variable to create their own variable such that thread1 reads it and make it say 100 and thread 2 reads it only when thread1 made the change and so on. After reading the value any changes one thread make to their variable should not affect the variable of other thread.

How can I do this?

The original problem is that I have 500 records that I want to fetch and I want to divide the work to different threads. At once I can only fetch 50 records. Now I want to fetch first 150 records using thread1 and next 150 using thread 2 and so on. I have information on how many total records are there in main thread (say variable totalRecords).

Now I need to send every thread information about starting record number and number of records one thread should fetch. How do I do it?

Comment: It is unclear what you need. Please elaborate.

Comment: i have 500 records that i want to divide the work to different threads. At once i can only fetch 50 records. Now i want to fetch first 150 records using thread1 and next 150 using thread 2 and so on. i have information on how many total records are there in main thread (say variable totalRecords). Now i need to send every thread information about  starting record number and number of records one thread should fetch. how do i do it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for ( int currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < totalRecords; currentRecord += 150 ) {
      final int startRecord = currentRecord;
      final int endRecord = startRecord + 150;

      service.execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          for ( int r = startRecord; r < endRecord && r < totalRecords; r++ ) {
            // Process record no. r
          }
        }
      });
   }
```